# The number operator in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, second-quantization

I have a question about the number operator as applied to a quantum gas containing a mixture of different spins. Let us say the total number operator $\hat{N}$ counts the total number of particles in a state, which we define in second quantization by the usual expression, $$\hat{N} = \sum_{rs}\sum_{\alpha \beta} \langle r,\alpha |n| s, \beta\rangle \hat{a}_{r,\alpha}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{s, \beta}.$$ Here $n$ is the number operator in first quantization. The states $|r\rangle,|s\rangle$ are states with definite momentum, and $|\alpha\rangle, |\beta\rangle$ are states with definite spin. The operator $\hat{a}$ is the annihilation operator. This expression for $\hat{N}$ can be reworked as follows, $$ \hat{N} = \int \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \  d^3 \mathbf{x'} \sum_{\alpha \beta} \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}_\alpha(\mathbf{x}) \langle \mathbf{x},\alpha |n|\mathbf{x'} ,\beta\rangle \hat{\psi}_\beta(\mathbf{x'}).$$ Here $\hat{\psi}(\mathbf{x})$ is the field operator corresponding with $\hat{a}$ and the wavefunction of the momentum states. Now this is where I encounter some confusion. I believe that the final second quantized form of the number operator looks like this,$$\hat{N} = \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \sum_{\alpha} \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}_\alpha(\mathbf{x}) \hat{\psi}_\alpha(\mathbf{x}).$$ This makes logical sense to me since it simply counts all the particles in the system. However getting to this form from the form derived above requires that the matrix element $\langle \mathbf{x},\alpha |n|\mathbf{x'} ,\beta\rangle  = \delta(\mathbf{x}'-\mathbf{x})\delta_\alpha^{\beta}$. I cannot find a way to fully understand why this is true. Is my derivation okay, or have I made a mistake somewhere? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $n=a^{\dagger}a$. Substitute for $n$. Then you will get $\langle \mathbf{x},\alpha |n|\mathbf{x'} ,\beta\rangle$=$\langle \mathbf{x},\alpha |a^{\dagger}a|\mathbf{x'} ,\beta\rangle $. But $a\left |\mathbf{x'} ,\beta\right>$ and $\left< \mathbf{x},\alpha \right |a^{\dagger} $  are state vectors in the Fock space. Dot product of these state vectors will give the desired result.

Comment: But isn't $n = a^{\dagger} a$ already a second quantized operator form? Correct me if I am wrong but this feels like using the result to proof itsself right. I am starting to think I dont understand the difference between the number operator in field operator form and just expressed as $a^{\dagger} a$ as you stated.

Comment: Oh.. perhaps I am wrong by taking $n=a^{\dagger}a$. Sorry, that I am also little bit confused. But I think since $n$ is number operator acting on $\left|x',\beta \right>$ a one particle state vector, will give an eigenvalue 1. Thus $\left< x,\alpha|n|x',\beta \right> =\left< x,\alpha|x',\beta \right>$.